# Can something be done about the greek captcha's?

Tags: bug, questions, captcha

I've again encountered one of these:

[image: Greek captcha]

Now I know the Greek Economy is dwindling and I appreciate StackExchange trying to help them out by OCR'ing there scripts, but for our poor Western Keyboards, those letters are a bit far fetched.

Since I always resort to just typing `Q*zi`, I don't think it's helping them anyway ;)

#### Seriously

There captcha's risk throwing off some users who are trying to ask a question. Can we only offer captcha's in the Western alphabet?

Comment: Just as nerdy side note: the greek letters are (upper case) phi Φ and (lower case) omega ω => ph and o

Comment: You're just doing it wrong http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lmp3uqivKf1qhixnvo1_400.png

Comment: LOL. I once saw some latin characters on the left... and some Arabic characters on the right. Luckily, it wasn't me. But my friend is stumped. Kind of like this: http://goo.gl/7PVjI

Answer (score 3):

Part of captcha is that it's helping OCR some books. One word is known, one is not.

These things appear in the unknown words. You don't need to get it right. Enter whatever you want for it. If enough people disagree on its definition it will be removed.

Because its a global system, that happens pretty quick. And if you insist, just hit the reload arrow button to the right and get a new one.

Comment: ...and if you have the ability/patience to enter in the non-latin characters it would be greatly appreciated